# How to truncate the hash function output in Solidity?

Tags: contract-design, hash

I'd like to keep an ID which is the first 32-bit of the hash function output in Solidity. I'm aware that "keccak256" output is of type:

```
bytes32
```

which is more larger than I want.

**Question**: How can I truncate the output of hash function (i.e. keccak256) from "bytes32" to "bytes2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly convert to `bytes2` from `bytes32`, as follows:

```
function test() constant returns(bytes2){
        return bytes2(keccak256("123"));
}
```

Hope it helps~